# A basic question of cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

From the material I am learning, for a chain complex  $ \cdots \mathop  \to \limits^\partial  {C_{n + 1}}\mathop  \to \limits^\partial  {C_n}\mathop  \to \limits^\partial  {C_{n - 1}}\mathop  \to \limits^\partial   \cdots $, the cochain group $C_n^ * $ if defined as $C_n^ *  = Hom({C_n},G)$ for a given group $G$. 
My question is that in what sense the cochain group $C_n^ *  = Hom({C_n},G)$ is a group, should it represent a homomorphism? or $C_n^ * $ is the image of some homomorphism to $G$ and thus is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: If $G$ is a group, then $Hom(C_n,G)$ is a group: $(\varphi \cdot \psi)(x):=\varphi(x)\cdot \psi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks very much, that helps a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The set $Hom(C_n,G) = \{\varphi \colon C_n \to G \mid \varphi \mbox{ is a homomorphism}\}$ is a group under point-wise addition so $\varphi_1+\varphi_2$ is defined by $(\varphi_1+\varphi_2)(x) = \varphi_1(x)+\varphi_2(x)$.

This is clearly an associative and commutative binary operation (because $G$ is an abelian group).

The identity is given by the zero-homomorphism $0$ given by $0(x) = 0_G$.

The inverse $\varphi'$ of $\varphi$ is given by $\varphi'(x) = -\varphi(x)$.